# How can you change the x-coords of a prepared boxplot in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, pdftex, boxplot

I want to visualize data with `pgfplot` `boxplots`. I am using `prepared` boxplots. The only problem that i have is that i don't know how to customize the x-axis values of the boxplot correctly. The x-axis values should be `128, 256, 512, 1024`. I already tried the `draw position` option but then the boxplots get squished:

[image: Squished Boxplots]

How can change the x-axis values while keeping the boxplots evenly spaces next to each other?
[image]

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        boxplot/draw direction=y,
        ]
        \addplot+ [boxplot prepared={
            draw position   =128,
            lower whisker   =649, 
            lower quartile  =749,
            median          =829, 
            upper quartile  =990,
            upper whisker   =3171
        },] coordinates {};
        \addplot+ [boxplot prepared={
            draw position   =256,
            lower whisker   =653, 
            lower quartile  =761,
            median          =898, 
            upper quartile  =1031,
            upper whisker   =3104},
        ] coordinates {};
        \addplot+ [boxplot prepared={
            draw position   =512,
            lower whisker   =782, 
            lower quartile  =812,
            median          =835, 
            upper quartile  =1144,
            upper whisker   =2418},
        ] coordinates {};
            \addplot+ [boxplot prepared={
            draw position   =1024,
            lower whisker   =822, 
            lower quartile  =826,
            median          =952, 
            upper quartile  =1208,
            upper whisker   =4454},
        ] coordinates {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the x-coords with the options:

```
xtick={1,2,3,4},
xticklabels={128, 256, 512, 1024}
```

Result:

[image: Resulting Boxplot]